# page doesn't work when uploaded

Tags: css

I designed a web page to be responsive using css. The page works perfectly on my computer and in the Firefox responsive simulator, but when I upload it, it's a wreck!

I was careful to upload every file and image I called in the page, but the page seems to be ignoring them. I checked similar questions here and read articles about the css hierarchy, but I'm not sure that is the only problem as the mounted page is even ignoring some of my html (for instance, the footer text). It also isn't fetching some of my images, even though the exact same image tag works in other pages at this level.

However, my popover works, so it must be reading the bootstrap css and jquery.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrappopover.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newraocss.css">
<title>Patricia S. Bowne fiction</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<!-- call javascript (necessary in the head for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

   <script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrappopover.js"></script>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>


<table class="border">

<tfoot>

<td class="footer" colspan=3>Copyright Patricia S. Bowne

</td>
</tfoot>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td class="header" colspan=3>
<div><br><h1>Patricia S. Bowne<h1></td>
</tr>

<tr> 

<td class="edge">


</td>


<td class="center"><p>Click on the title below each thumbnail for a description of the book, including links to purchase and read excerpts. To hide the description, click on the title again.</p>

<div class="books">
<div class="thumbnail"><img class="med" src="images/Pigeons-510.jpg"><br><a class="button" href="javascript://" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="" data-content="Some jobs are more trouble than they're worth ... 
the Demonology department's newest member, Hiram Rho, tries to gain his footing among colleagues with specialties like vampirology, classical lechery, and postmodern feminist demonology. Before Rho has been on campus a month he has acquired an affectionate demon with a plan to take over the department, the two senior demonologists have lost their souls and their health insurance, and Rho's problems have embroiled everyone from the mysterious Alchemy faculty to the pigeons on his window ledge. Available from:<br> <a href='http://www.double-dragon-ebooks.com/single.php?ISBN=1-55404-808-7' title='test add link'>Double Dragon E-Books</a><br><a href='http://www.amazon.com/Advice-From-Pigeons-ebook/dp/B004MYFSHU/' title='test add link'>Amazon Kindle store</a>" data-original-title="The Royal Academy I: Advice from Pigeons">The Royal Academy I:<br> Advice from Pigeons</a></div>
</div><script>$("[data-toggle=popover]")
.popover({html:true})</script>


<p><div class="reviews"><b>Reviewers say:</div>             
</td>
<td class="edge">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

and here's the link to see how it's appearing online: http://www.raosyth.com/respshell.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Open the browser's console and checkout the errors you're getting

Comment: Check your browser console (f12) for clues. You're missing some assets on the site, that will show you what isn't loading.

Comment: First, your doctype is one that you shouldn't be using for new web pages since 1999. Change that to <!DOCTYPE html> though that may not fix anything.

Comment: Remove the meta tag containing the charset for ISO-xxx cause you duplicate it later with the proper utf-8 one.

Answer (score 1):

as others have said open your console and have a look at the errors. you are getting 404 errors;

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found) http://www.raosyth.com/images/Pigeons-510.jpg
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://www.raosyth.com/images/afpnowords.jpg
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://www.raosyth.com/bootstrappopover.css
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

have you uploaded the above files to your webserver? if you have please double check the path references to the files

Comment: You guys are great! I had a wide variety of problems and you caught them all (I hope). Omar, you were right - one of the files I needed had not uploaded. The others were present and the paths were right - except that I had not known 'jpg' was case-sensitive, so I had their names wrong.

Comment: The bigger issue was that it was not being responsive, and that must have been due to some of the outdated code in the head because when I fixed it as Rob suggested, those problems went away.

Comment: But I just realized that the subpages it links to are also fixed now, and I didn't change their heads. So this remains a real mystery. Why was it not responsive (basically ignoring the table width definitions in the newraocss), though it paid attention to the div styles in the same file?